# Clicking download button downloads table AND opens a new tab

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to be able to download a DataTable as a .csv from my Dash app using a button click. If possible I don't want to use the export_format option in the DataTable. Using the code below, clicking the button downloads the table *and* opens the app in a new tab. No error messages are generated by the button-click/download callbacks. How do I prevent a new tab from opening when the button is clicked?

I've been relying on this answer so far: [Dash Data table download to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485943/dash-data-table-download-to-excel)

The answer provided here also downloads but opens a new tab: [download csv file in Dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61784556/download-csv-file-in-dash)

I found this related issue (https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/issues/1247) but I'm not code savvy enough to determine what is relevant to my case or how to translate the solution into python.

Python version 3.9.5 | Dash version 2.4.1

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import io
import dash
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, dash_table, callback_context
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

root, dirs, files = next(os.walk("./data/current/"))

for f in range(len(files)):
    prior = pd.read_csv(root+files[f],header=0,delimiter=',',nrows=5,keep_default_na=False)

tab1 = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.A(id='priortable',href='',target='_blank',children=[html.Button("Download Prioritization Table",id="btn_pt",n_clicks=0)])
        ]),
    html.Br(),
    dash_table.DataTable(id='mesa', data=prior.to_dict('records'),columns=[{'name':i,'id':i} for i in prior.columns]),
    dcc.Download(id="download_pt")
    ])

app = dash.Dash(__name__,suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs(id='tabs', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Prioritization',value='tab-1')]),
    html.Div(id='TABS')
    ])

@app.callback(Output('TABS', 'children'),
              Input('tabs', 'value'))

def render_content(tab):
    if tab == 'tab-1':
        return tab1

@app.callback(
    Output('download_pt','data'),
    Input('btn_pt','n_clicks'),
    State('mesa','data'),
    prevent_initial_callback=True
)

def download_pt(n_clicks, table_data):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(table_data)
    filename = ''
    fmt = "csv"
    if not n_clicks > 0:
        raise PreventUpdate
    download_buffer = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(download_buffer, index=False)
    download_buffer.seek(0)
    filename = 'prioritization_table_all_fires.%s' % fmt

    return dict(content=download_buffer.getvalue(), filename=filename)

@app.server.route('/downloads/<path:path>')

def serve_static(path):
    root_dir = os.getcwd()
    return flask.send_from_directory(os.path.join(root_dir,'download'), path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Hoping it's a goofy detail that I'm missing but either way help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By reading the Apache2 error.log I found two solutions in my context. One solution is for downloading spreadsheet/table files, like .csv; the other solution worked for plots downloading as .pdf.

1. I ended up creating .csv files for download as part of app startup so the download button is retrieving an existing file, not creating it. The issue in this context was the file name the callback searched for didn't match the name the file was saved as. When the expected file name couldn't be found, the Dash app opened a new tab. Fix the file name issue, fix the tab opening.
2. To fix the .pdf download problem, the Apache2 error.log said to run `pip install -U kaleido`. When this command was run as root user, the .pdf download worked without opening a new tab.